# core data - is it possible to avoid save managedObjectContext in main thread?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

i'm try to do some multithread sync for core data. But in case, when i have to do save in main thread:

```
- (void)importerDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    NSLog(@"MERGE in destination controller");
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [[delegate managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(importerDidSave:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

i have sometime freezes of main thread (in that case i have spin). All interface views is connect to array controllers, which connect to AppDelegate moc.
So, some questions about design:

1. can i avoid freeze on main interface and merge managed object context outside main thread?
2. is spin can be avoided, if i will connect all arrays to another managedobjectcontext? how i can avoid issue, when context, which was created, don't have inside changes, which will merge after create this object?

any help will appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You'll always need to update the context that your controllers are bound to, and since this is UI stuff, you'll need to do that on the main thread.

I'm slightly confused as to why you've coded it the way you have though. This seems simpler to me:

```
- (void)importerDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {

    NSLog(@"MERGE in destination controller");

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[delegate managedObjectContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

Does using that code improve the performance at all?